# Makeup screen for Full HD Android Device

Tags: android

i have folder values - for phone size and values-sw600dp - for tablet. In HTC One V and Archos GamePad app look good, but in Nexus 5 (Full HD) makeup don`t look good. How i can fix it?

Comment: Nexus screen is 1920x1080 and HTC One V is 800x480 pixels. Also their screen density is 445 and 252 ppi respectively. So you need to create different drawables and values folder for different screen density screens

Comment: how should I name the folder to the program will understand that the resolution of Full HD to take resources from the folder?

Comment: values-w820dp for screens with more than 820dp of available width, similarly for other screen sizes. In drawables you might already be having drawable-xxhdpi etc etc

Comment: i make folder "values-w820dp" and file "dimens.xml" i set in this file  other value , but it`s don`t work

Comment: See some sample project's `res` folder online. This will help you with different folder names and what values you need to set in those. I am sure you'll figure it out quite easily. :)

Comment: in folder values-w820dp will handle device which is more 820dpi, but Nexus5 has 480 dpi